# Get spinnaker pipeline logs

Tags: spinnaker

As the method https://spinnaker.io/reference/api/docs.html#api-Pipelinecontroller-getPipelineLogsUsingGET is not available, according to https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/5550, is there any alternative method to get the pipeline execution logs from spinnaker? Looking for an endpoint in spinnaker, which will provide the log of a pipeline when called...

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the execution log for a pipeline with this API:

```
https://{spinnaker-url}/pipelines/{executionID}
```

Comment: could you please describe little more about the response, that was in return to the above endpoint you were mentioning... i tied with pipelines/{id}. But it contains pipeline stages, triggers and other metadata but missing logs. Thank you

Comment: I get a JSON with the details about the pipeline as well the output of each stage within.. the logs related to each stage will be part of it.. are you looking for something else?

Comment: I have seen the JSON which contains the metadata, stage info etc. But it wont contain the console output from job that was deployed in deploy stage of the pipeline. Please let me know if i am missing anything...

Comment: By entering that URL in the browser one is directed to the pipeline page. From there, we're back to square one: click around but you won't find any logging information from the stages.

Comment: *Update*: click on the very small "View as JSON", beautify the resulting blob and look for `exception` or `message` or `resultObjects`